Video Loading Issue on Chapter Switch in FilamentPHP Custom Page
I'm working on a learning management system using Laravel, FilamentPHP, AlpineJs and Livewire, and facing an issue with loading videos in my Filament custom page. The video for the current chapter loads fine initially, but when I switch chapters, the new video doesn't load as expected. Here’s a snippet of my code:
<x-filament-panels::page>
    @if ($this->currentChapter)
        <div x-data="{
            videoSrc: '{{ $currentChapter->getFirstMediaUrl('course-unit-chapter-videos') }}',
            videoId: 'video-{{ $currentChapter->id }}'
        }" class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-8" x-init="$watch('videoSrc', (value) => {
            $refs.videoPlayer.src = value;
            $refs.videoPlayer.load();
            $refs.videoPlayer.play();
        })">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:col-span-2">
                {{-- Chapter Video --}}
                <div class="relative max-w-5xl mx-auto">
                    <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg overflow-hidden">
                        <video x-ref="videoPlayer" :id="videoId" x-bind:src="videoSrc" width="1920"
                            height="1080" loop controls>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Navigation buttons -->
                <div class="flex justify-between mt-4">
                    <x-filament::button wire:click="previousChapter" :disabled="!$this->hasPreviousChapter">
                        Previous Chapter
                    </x-filament::button>
                    <x-filament::button wire:click="nextChapter" :disabled="!$this->hasNextChapter">
                        Next Chapter
                    </x-filament::button>
                </div>

                {{-- Chapter Content --}}
                <x-filament::section collapsible collapsed>
                    <x-slot name="heading">
                        Chapter content
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="description">
                        {{ $currentChapter->name }}
                    </x-slot>

                    <article class="prose dark:prose-invert prose-img:rounded-xl prose-img:mx-auto max-w-full">
                        {!! (new Parsedown())->text($currentChapter->content) !!}
                    </article>
                </x-filament::section>
            </div>

            {{-- Course chapters --}}
            <x-filament::section>
                <x-slot name="heading">
                    Course units
                </x-slot>

                <x-slot name="description">
                    {{ $record->name }}
                </x-slot>

                <ul class="flex flex-col space-y-2">

                    @foreach ($record->course_units as $unit)
                        <li>
                            <strong
                                class="block text-md font-medium uppercase text-gray-950 dark:text-white">{{ $loop->iteration }}.
                                {{ $unit->name }} </strong>

                            <ul class="px-4 py-2">
                                @foreach ($unit->topics as $topic)
                                    <li x-data="{ open: false }">
                                        <details class="group [&_summary::-webkit-details-marker]:hidden"
                                            :open="open">
                                            <summary @click.prevent="open = !open"
                                                class="flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-between rounded-lg py-2 hover:text-gray-600 text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                                                <span class="text-sm font-medium"> {{ $topic->name }} </span>

                                                <span class="shrink-0 transition duration-300"
                                                    :class="{ '-rotate-180': open }">
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5"
                                                        viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                                            d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                                                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                                            </summary>

                                            <ul class="space-y-1 px-2">
                                                @foreach ($topic->topic_chapters as $chapter)
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div @click="videoSrc = '{{ $chapter->getFirstMediaUrl('course-unit-chapter-videos') }}'; videoId = 'video-{{ $chapter->id }}'"
                                                            wire:click="changeChapter({{ $chapter->id }})"
                                                            class="block cursor-pointer rounded-lg px-4 py-2 text-xs font-medium hover:text-gray-700 transition duration-75 hover:bg-gray-100 focus-visible:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-white/5 dark:focus-visible:bg-white/5 {{ $currentChapter->id === $chapter->id ? 'text-primary-600 dark:text-primary-400 bg-gray-100 dark:bg-white/5' : 'text-gray-950 dark:text-white' }}">
                                                            {{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $chapter->name }}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                        </details>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </x-filament::section>
        </div>
    @else
        <p>No chapters available for this course.</p>
    @endif
</x-filament-panels::page>


When I switch chapters, the new video's src gets updated, but the video element doesn't load or play the new video as expected. There are no errors in the console, and I'm unsure what's going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
